# Split a word string with a comma in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, plugins

I have a string of text in a recipe ingredient group that needs to be divided with a comma when notes are specified for any given ingredient. For example - it will display "1 onion red" but I'd like it to display "1 onion, red".

I've tried using implode but it didn't add the comma at all. So clearly I am overlooking something/not understanding enough.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if ( $ingredient['notes'] ) : ?>
<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes"><?php echo $ingredient['notes']; ?>
</span>
<?php endif; // Ingredient notes. ?>
```

I have tried these snippets with no luck -

```
// Example 1 -

<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes"><?php echo implode(",", $ingredient['notes']); ?></span>

// Example 2 - 

<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes"><?php echo $ingredient[',' 'notes']; ?></span>

// Example 3 - this one created a big gap between the ingredient and the note for the ingredient

<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes"><p>,</p><? php echo $ingredient['notes']; ?></span>
```

[Here's an example of a post with a recipe so you can see the plugin in action and how it is currently displaying ingredients](https://www.100daysofrealfood.com/almond-maple-shortbread-cookies/)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the value and type of `$ingredient['notes']`? Is it an array? Implode only works on an array.

Comment: It isn't an array. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the notes is stores in `$ingredient['notes']` and you just need a comma before it, you can just do:

```
<span class="wprm-recipe-ingredient-notes">, <? php echo $ingredient['notes']; ?></span>
```

Comment: lol. I knew it was something so basic that I was overlooking. Thank you!!!